# What is the difference of a cloudfoundry "service broker" and its "service broker worker"?

Tags: cloud-foundry, paas, pcf, cf-bosh

Most of the cloudfoundry service tiles install a service broker AND a service broker worker.

I understand that the broker is receiving Service Broker API requests from the Cloud Controller (CC), and hosts the primary dashboard UI for all service types.
So the broker registers with the marketplace and on a create-instance creates vms and installs the service on them and offers UI parts for managing the instances.

But what exactly is the responsibility of the broker worker?
With which components is it communicating when and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broker worker, like with the Spring Cloud Services tile, is responsible for doing the work that might take a long time.  Rather than tying up a thread in the broker to do this, it's handed off to the broker worker which processes the tasks.

> But what exactly is the responsibility of the broker worker?

It depends on the tile, but most likely the broker worker is going to be responsible for creating the actual backing resources for the service.  Again, in the case of Spring Cloud Services, it's the broker worker that manages the backing service application instances.

https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/1-5/service-broker-and-instances.html#service-instance-management

Other tiles/brokers workers may do different things, but this is generally going to be where the expensive work to set up a service happens.

> With which components is it communicating when and why?

This will be more specific to the tile.  In the case of SCS, the broker worker is primarily talking to the API (i.e. Cloud Controller) to manage backing service application instances.  That said, a broker worker could do all sorts of things.  Call out to AWS or another IaaS to create something, call out to Bosh to dynamically deploy something, etc.  It just depends on what the service tile is going to do.

Hope that helps!

Comment: so the service broker itself is just a tiny app fullfilling the service broker interface

a) to register the services and plans with the marketplace and

b) to kick of a "do it" thread in the broker worker on a create-/update-delete-instance

right?

In "the normal case" is the work done in a thread inside the worker, or does it also happen that a separate process or even a VM is spun up for this?

Comment: Yes, that's the gist of it.  It's hard to say what the "normal" case is for where the work occurs.  That would likely depend on the implementation of the broker.  In SCS, the work occurs in a thread in the broker worker process.  I suppose other processes could be forked off, if there was a need.  If you were using `bosh` to dynamically deploy something, it'd be likely that the broker worker would shell out to the bosh cli to handle that work.

Comment: To reinforce what Daniel said, I don't think there is a "normal case". There are lots of ways to implement the asynchronous behavior required of a service broker when service instance provisioning will take more than a few seconds. It just depends on the language the broker is implemented in, libraries used by the broker, the nature of the service resources being provisioned, and architectural decisions made by the service authors.